# Requesting explanation of of inner workings of Python's "super()" function

Tags: python, inheritance, super, diamond-problem

Hyia,

I know how to use the super() function in Python but I do not have a mental picture of its inner workings. The simple full working code at the end made me think: who is responsible for the mro? It seems as if it's passed along, making a new class responsible for the proper and complete execution order.

So who knows the details of its inner workings? Let's use the code below as a basis. I tried to debug, but my free PyCharm IDE didn't allow to step into code, it only iterates through my own code.

```
class Artist:
    def __init__(self):
        print("Artist")


class Sia(Artist):
    def __init__(self):
        print("Sia")
        super().__init__()


class Portishead(Artist):
    def __init__(self):
        print("Portishead")
        Artist.__init__(self)  # !!!!!


class TikTokFan(Portishead, Sia):
    def __init__(self):
        print("TikTokFan")
        super().__init__()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    ttf = TikTokFan()
```

Comment: Well-known article on this subject: https://rhettinger.wordpress.com/2011/05/26/super-considered-super/

Comment: Finished reading it minutes before your response. Albeit an interesting article, I don't have a clear view on how it actually works. It's entirely not clear to me how the mro is being tracked.